# Acceder a valores de un Map usando la misma sintaxis con la que se accede a un campo java (preferiblemente sin librerias de terceros)

Tags: java, map, atributos

## Cuerpo nuevo

En java, cuando creamos un record, lo hacemos especificando los campos manualmente.

```
public record Registro(String a, int b) {}
```

Pero yo necesito crear un record de tal manera que pueda inicializarlo con una cantidad variable de parametros y dichos parametros deben de tener nombres variados (en realidad, esos nombres dependen del nombre de la clase de la instancia, yo resuelvo eso).

> vease el cuerpo viejo de la pregunta para ver mis intentos de resolver
> esta cuestión.

¿Como creo un record cumpliendo estas condiciones?

**Edit** Intentando crear la clase dinamicamente, empecé a pensar que intentar esto es como matar moscas a cañonasos, por lo requerido para generar records dinamicamente (como una versión especial de java que pueda compilar en tiempo de ejecución). De todas maneras, pude resolverlo cambiando mi forma de programar. Pero si la pusiera como respuesta, no respondería la pregunta.

Aun así, si alguien está interesado en dar una respuesta (que me vea ver una mejor forma de lograr esto o simplemente generando codigo dinamicamente que fue el enfoque que usé) es bienvenido.

---

## Cuerpo anterior

#### Un ejemplo de Python

En Python, si quiero lograr una especie de diccionario (el equivalente a HashMap en Python) en el cual se pueda acceder a sus valores usando atributos, lo haría así:

```
class AttrDict:
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        if attr == "dict":
            return super().__getattribute__("__dict__")
        else:
            return self.dict[attr]
```

Usando el ejemplo anterior, se logra acceder al diccionario interno usando el atributo dict y cualquier otro atributo se usará para obtener el valor contenido en el diccionario para la clave.

#### Mis intentos de implementar esto en java

Ahora, estoy aprendiendo java y me encuentro que es más dificil usar azucar sintactica.

Para lograr lo mencionado antes, investigué lo siguiente:

- Como crear clases dinamicamente. La mejor solución es esta https://stackoverflow.com/a/2320465/12913664, en la cual se escribe un código programaticamente y se compila. Pero no me parece una buena solución.
- Crear campos dinamicamente. Encontré esta duda pero no es satisfactoria, ya que menciona librerías externas, y otra dice que no es posible.
- Como modificar la forma en la que java accede a los atributos de instancia para que devuelva el valor asociado. Para los que saben Python, esto significa buscar un equivalente al metodo magico `__getattribute__` en java.
- Me fijé si java ya proporciona una forma de hacer esto. Lo más cercano fue la clase [Atributes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/Attributes.html), pero pareciera, por los pocos ejemplos que pude encontrar, que esta clase no hace lo que busco.

#### La pregunta

¿Hay una forma de lograr acceder a un valor de una instancia de Map, o crear mi propia clase derivada de Map, de tal manera que pueda codificar con un estilo similar a éste?:

```
MyMap<int> mapa = new MyMap<int>()
mapa.put("cadena", 1)
mapa.put("hola_mundo", 2)

System.out.println(mapa.cadena)
```

Muestre en consola

```
1
```

**Edit** Un enum no sirve a mi proposito, ya que necesito que cambie en tiempo de ejecución y, ademas, guardar instancias de otra clase como valores. Por el mismo motivo, tampoco puedo usar un Record.

**Edit 2** Para mi caso particular, solo necesito inicializarla creando campos dinamicamente con un bucle for y a partir de ahí, solo usarla para acceder a los valores guardados.

Quiero hacer algo como un record o un enum, pero inicializarlo dinamicamente, en lugar de preescribir todos los campos.

Comment: *de tal manera que pueda codificar con un estilo similar a éste* -> Una de las cosas que implica cambiar de lenguaje es acostumbrarse a la manera de trabajar de cada uno. Lo que quieres hacer podría hacerse si generas una clase de manera dinámica con sus atributos públicos... pero tendrías que modificarla CADA VEZ QUE AÑADES UN VALOR AL MAPA! Me imagino que el *golpe* de rendimiento haría que eso sea inviable en una aplicación real. Por si acaso, me guardo la pregunta porque me parece muy interesante simplemente por ver hasta donde vale la pena llegar para hacerlo :) Ojalá encuentren la manera

Comment: @Benito-B No si lo que hago sería inicializarla una sola vez. Una vez incializada con sus respectivos valores, no pienso modificarla. Por cierto, gracias!

Comment: Creo que se me ocurrió una nueva versión de la pregunta c:

Comment: Con `Map<String,Object>` lo consigues, casi como en tu ejemplo, la diferencia es que el acceso es mas consistente (put vs get): `mapa.get("cadena")`. De la parte dinámica ¿Qué te interesa mas? ¿La definición o la instanciación?.

Comment: @Sal, lo se, en realidad, quiero que me ayuden a darme un lujo, por que lo que justo quiero lograr, es evitar usar .get("cadena"). Si no con la sintaxis .cadena, que es más limpia, o en su defecto .cadena() o  .getCadena(). Pero gracias igual por la propuesta c:

Comment: La instanciación en realidad.

Comment: @Benito-B sabes como crear una clase dinamica? Por que si se puede, solo necesito crearla una vez y ya. Ni siquiera necesito modificar sus valores una vez inicializada.

Comment: @DanteS. Yo creo que crear una clase dinámica tampoco te va a servir, lo más probable es que tengas que utilizar `invoke` para acceder a los campos. Años que dejé Java, pero hasta donde recuerdo lo que pides no es posible

Comment: @Yussef entiendo. Hasta ahora, la mejor idea que se me está ocurriendo es generar una clase dinamica escribiendo programaticamente código y luego ejecutarlo. Y no me parece tan mala idea. Si funciona, publicaré una respuesta.

Comment: Pero entonces ¿tienes la definición en tiempo de diseño? ¿o compilarías en tiempo de ejecución?.

Comment: Me da curiosidad saber si lo logras, yo creo que no es posible. Es decir vas a poder crear la clase dinámicamente, lo que NO vas a poder hacer es invocar al campo de esta manera `mapa.cadena` porque necesitaras usar la función `invoke` algo así te puede quedar (no necesariamente igual) `mapa.invoke("cadena")`, que NO es lo que tú quieres y para eso mejor ocupas un `Map`. Y es porque Java es fuertemente tipado y no tiene algo parecido a un `dynamics` como lo tiene C#

Comment: @Yussef no lo probé (y no creo que lo vaya poner a prueba), pero la idea es generar una clase dinamicamente para luego instanciarla. Al ser una instancia de clase y no un resultado directo de la relexión de Java, ese problema desaparece.

Comment: Mi java no es tan avanzado como para responderte (habría puesto una respuesta si así lo fuera). El problema que veo, es que esa clase dinámica se crea en tiempo de ejecución, por lo que una expresión de este tipo: `mapa.cadena` dará error al compilarlo, es decir antes que pueda crearse esa clase.

Comment: @Yussef El plan es generar una clase con unos campos creados a partir de la lista. Esa clase, estaría almacenada en una cadena y sería compilada en tiempo de ejecución, luego instanciada y recién a esa instancia le haría "mapa.cadena". A eso estaba apuntando hasta que vi que le estaba fabricando un cañon para aplastar moscas. Por que daría error?

Comment: Porque todos eso que quieres hacer es para poder colocar `mapa.cadena`, pero esto no existe antes de hayas compilado, entonces el mero hecho de tener esa instrucción no te dejará compilar (es como el dicho "que es primero, el huevo o la gallina). El problema no está en crear la clase de manera dinámica, eso seguro es posible, el problema está en ocupar la sintaxis que tu deseas, porque a menos que `mapa.cadena` lo ingreses como string en una función del tipo `invoke` yo por lo menos no veo como. Ahora bien, Java dejé de ocuparlo hacer 10 años, por eso no me atrevo a asegurarlo en un 100%

Comment: @yussef tiene sentido. No llegué hasta ese punto (es muy dificil compilar en tiempo de ejecución en java). Esperaré a alguien que la responda por si resulta util a alguien.

Comment: Quizás existen técnicas de metaprogramación que desconozco.  Por otro lado, creo que en C# se puede hacer, y es porque existe el tipo de datos `dynamics` que evita ese problema al compilar, básicamente le dice al compilador que el objeto es cualquier cosa y que tú te haces responsable de él y que no lo revise. Pero este tipo de datos no existe en JAVA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nota: esta respuesta solo sirve si se conocen todas las claves que se usarán y no se piensa añadir ninguna en tiempo de ejecución.
Es posible que esta tecnica no sea lo más conveniente si va a haber demasiados campos sin uso, ya que tengo entendido que en java los campos SIEMPRE tienen un valor.

---

No se puede exactamente lograr lo planteado en la pregunta, pero si se puede crear una clase con los campos a usar predefinidos e instanciarla.

Los pasos a seguir si:

- Querés guardarlo como campo en una clase:

  1. Crear una clase estatica con los campos que se van a usar como publicos
  2. Crear un campo en la clase objetivo usando de tipo la clase creada en el paso 1.
  3. En donde sea necesario (habitualmente el constructor) instanciarla.

  ```
  public class Main{
      class Dict{
          public int a;
          public int b;
      }

      private Dict dict;

      public static void main(String[] args){
          this.dict = new Dict();
          this.dict.a = 1;
          this.dict.b = 2;
      }
  }
  ```
- Querés guardarlo como variable local y usar esta "estructura" una sola vez:

  1. Crear una clase dentro del método con los campos que se van a usar como publicos y estaticos. Ya podemos usar esta clase para nuestro proposito.

  ```
  public class Main{
      public static void main(String[] args){
          class dict{
              static public int a;
              static public int b;
          }

          dict.a = 1;
          dict.b = 2;
      }
  }
  ```
- Querés guardarlo como variable local y reutilizar la estructura:

  1. Hacer lo mismo que en el primer item pero crear la clase dentro de la función y guardar la instancia en una variable local en lugar de un campo.

  ```
  public class Main{
      public static void main(String[] args){
          class Dict{
              static public int a;
              static public int b;
          }

          Dict dict1 = new Dict();
          dict1.a = 1;
          dict1.b = 2;

          Dict dict2 = new Dict();
          dict2.a = 1;
          dict2.b = 2;
      }
  }
  ```

---

En muchos casos de uso, probablemente usar esta tecnica creando una clase en un archivo separado sea la mejor opción. Pero hoy me encontré en un caso de uso en el cual siento que las tecnicas antes mencionadas son buena opción.